# django 'LineChart' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I am trying to make a line chart in django, I am using the jchart module, When I try and load the chart I get the below error.

error
    'LineChart' object has no attribute 'get'

full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'LineChart' object has no attribute 'get'
```

view

```
from jchart import Chart
from jchart.config import Axes, DataSet, rgba


class LineChart(Chart):
    chart_type = 'line'
    responsive = False
    scales = {
        'xAxes': [Axes(type='time', position='bottom')],
    }

    def get_datasets(self, **kwargs):
        data = [{'y': 0, 'x': '2017-01-02T00:00:00'}, {'y': 1, 'x': '2017-01-03T00:00:00'}, {'y': 4, 'x': '2017-01-04T00:00:00'}, {'y': 9, 'x': '2017-01-05T00:00:00'}, {'y': 16, 'x': '2017-01-06T00:00:00'}, {'y': 25, 'x': '2017-01-07T00:00:00'}, {'y': 36, 'x': '2017-01-08T00:00:00'}, {'y': 49, 'x': '2017-01-09T00:00:00'}, {'y': 64, 'x': '2017-01-10T00:00:00'}, {'y': 81, 'x': '2017-01-11T00:00:00'}, {'y': 100, 'x': '2017-01-12T00:00:00'}, {'y': 121, 'x': '2017-01-13T00:00:00'}, {'y': 144, 'x': '2017-01-14T00:00:00'}, {'y': 169, 'x': '2017-01-15T00:00:00'}, {'y': 196, 'x': '2017-01-16T00:00:00'}, {'y': 225, 'x': '2017-01-17T00:00:00'}, {'y': 256, 'x': '2017-01-18T00:00:00'}, {'y': 289, 'x': '2017-01-19T00:00:00'}, {'y': 324, 'x': '2017-01-20T00:00:00'}, {'y': 361, 'x': '2017-01-21T00:00:00'}, {'y': 400, 'x': '2017-01-22T00:00:00'}, {'y': 441, 'x': '2017-01-23T00:00:00'}, {'y': 484, 'x': '2017-01-24T00:00:00'}, {'y': 529, 'x': '2017-01-25T00:00:00'}, {'y': 576, 'x': '2017-01-26T00:00:00'}, {'y': 625, 'x': '2017-01-27T00:00:00'}, {'y': 676, 'x': '2017-01-28T00:00:00'}, {'y': 729, 'x': '2017-01-29T00:00:00'}, {'y': 784, 'x': '2017-01-30T00:00:00'}, {'y': 841, 'x': '2017-01-31T00:00:00'}, {'y': 900, 'x': '2017-02-01T00:00:00'}]

        return [DataSet(
            type='line',
            label='Time Series',
            data=data,
        )]

    def some_view(request):
        render(request, 'polls/chart.html', {
        'line_chart': LineChart(),
    })
```

url

```
url(r'^polls/bubble/$', views.LineChart, name='bubble'),
```

chart.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load jchart %}

 {% block content %}

{{ line_chart.as_html }}

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have added the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the view `some_view` in your URL pattern, not the class `LineChart`.

```
url(r'^polls/bubble/$', views.some_view, name='bubble'),
```

Also, check that the indentation for `some_view` is correct. It might just be a mistake in your question instead of your actual code, but you currently have `some_view` as a method of the `LineChart` class. It should be:

```
class LineChart(Chart):
    chart_type = 'line'
    responsive = False
    ...

def some_view(request):
    render(request, 'polls/chart.html', {
    'line_chart': LineChart(),
})
```